# DevExpress XafCallback: how to do process action for 5 different buttons in ListEditor

Tags: button, callback, devexpress, action, xaf

I have a ListEditor called OperatorListEditor. There I create a table with 5 Linkbuttons. Each button has different actions. How can I access them from OperatorViewController and how should I get them from ProcessAction ?
Or maybe I can create these buttons in OperatorViewController?
Should I create 5 callbacks? And if it's what should I do, how?
Explain with more details, please. I'm a noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more XAF-Friendly approach, you should write 5 simple actions on the OperatorViewController, instead of creating linkbuttons on a custom ListEditor.

To move your action from toolbar to inline, set the action's SelectionDependencyType - to RequireSingleObject and Category to RecordEdit, this will create a GridViewDataActionColumn in runtime. There are serveral examples in Support Center about how to customize a GridViewDataActionColumn as needed.

See also:
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2737